# How to keep both filters active using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to filter a table on columns department and location. 
These filters are working one at a time.

I am clueless on how to make both filters working at the same time.

For example if I need to filter all "Engineering" departments with the "New York" location. 
How can I make the code remember and apply both filters at the same time? Thanks for the help.

```js
//function to filter the departments based on selection
function filterTextDept() {
  var rexD = new RegExp($('#filterTextDept').val());
  if (rexD == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rexD.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('#filterTextDept').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}

//function to filter the locations based on selection
function filterTextLoc() {
  var rexL = new RegExp($('#filterTextLoc').val());
  if (rexL == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rexL.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('#filterTextLoc').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <select id="filterTextDept" onchange="filterTextDept()">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
    <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
    <option value="Data Science">Data Science</option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
    <option value="Growth">Growth</option>
    <option value="Product Management">Product Management</option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
  </select> 
  <select id="filterTextLoc" onchange="filterTextLoc()">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Location</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
    <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
  </select>
  <table id="jobTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-list-search">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Account Manager</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Account%20Manager">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Associate Account Manager</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Associate%20Account%20Manager">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Diego</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Francisco or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Engineering</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Engineering">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Product Management, Fraud Risk</td>
        <td>Product Management</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Product%20Management,%20Fraud%20Risk">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Strategic Alliances</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Diego</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Strategic%20Alliances">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Head of Solution Consulting</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>San Diego, New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Head%20of%20Solution%20Consulting">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>IT Risk and Compliance Officer</td>
        <td>Compliance</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="IT%20Risk%20and%20Compliance%20Officer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Lead Data Scientist</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Lead%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Data Engineer</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Data%20Engineer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Data Scientist</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Product Manager, Document Verification</td>
        <td>Product Management</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Product%20Manager,%20Document%20Verification">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>Chennai</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Software%20Engineer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Software Engineer (All Levels)</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Software%20Engineer%20(All%20Levels)">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Solution Consultant</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>San Francisco or New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Solution%20Consultant">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Staff Software Engineer - Chennai</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>Chennai</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Chennai">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Staff Software Engineer - Core Platform</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Core%20Platform">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible. You were very close to the solution
My approach is to run all the filters every time.

**EDIT**

You can check the count of line displayed with `$('.content:visible').length`

```js
function updateFilters () {
clearFilter()
filterTextDept()
filterTextLoc()
postFilter()
}
function postFilter() {
  $visibleLinesCount = $('.content:visible').length
  if ($visibleLinesCount === 0) {
    // here your logic when no result 
    console.log('no result')
  } else if ($visibleLinesCount === 1) {
    console.log('only one result')
  } else {
    console.log($visibleLinesCount + ' results')
  }
}
//function to filter the departments based on selection
function filterTextDept() {
  var rexD = new RegExp($('#filterTextDept').val());
  if (!$('#filterTextDept').val()) {
    // nothing selected
    return;
  } else if (rexD == "/all/") {
    return;
  } else {
    //$('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return !rexD.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
  }
}

//function to filter the locations based on selection
function filterTextLoc() {
  var rexL = new RegExp($('#filterTextLoc').val());
  if (!$('#filterTextLoc').val()) {
    // nothing selected
    return;
  } else if (rexL == "/all/") {
    return;
  } else {
    //$('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return !rexL.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <select id="filterTextDept" onchange="updateFilters()">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
    <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
    <option value="Data Science">Data Science</option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
    <option value="Growth">Growth</option>
    <option value="Product Management">Product Management</option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
  </select> 
  <select id="filterTextLoc" onchange="updateFilters()">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Location</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
    <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
  </select>
  <table id="jobTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-list-search">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Account Manager</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Account%20Manager">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Associate Account Manager</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Associate%20Account%20Manager">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Diego</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Francisco or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Engineering</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Engineering">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Product Management, Fraud Risk</td>
        <td>Product Management</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Product%20Management,%20Fraud%20Risk">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Director of Strategic Alliances</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>San Diego</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Director%20of%20Strategic%20Alliances">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Head of Solution Consulting</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>San Diego, New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Head%20of%20Solution%20Consulting">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>IT Risk and Compliance Officer</td>
        <td>Compliance</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="IT%20Risk%20and%20Compliance%20Officer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Lead Data Scientist</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Lead%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Data Engineer</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Data%20Engineer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Data Scientist</td>
        <td>Data Science</td>
        <td>New York or Remote</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Product Manager, Document Verification</td>
        <td>Product Management</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Product%20Manager,%20Document%20Verification">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Senior Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>Chennai</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Senior%20Software%20Engineer">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Software Engineer (All Levels)</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Software%20Engineer%20(All%20Levels)">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Solution Consultant</td>
        <td>Growth</td>
        <td>San Francisco or New York</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Solution%20Consultant">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Staff Software Engineer - Chennai</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>Chennai</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Chennai">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="content">
        <td>Staff Software Engineer - Core Platform</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
        <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
        <td>
          <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Core%20Platform">Link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution it works flawlessly. Is there any way to detect when no matches are found based on the two filters and display a message like "no results found"? appreciate your help

Comment: i update my code : to display a specific message, you can write in your HTML the message and display it only when there is no result.

Comment: amazing. Thank you once again :) really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This snippet does it with a logical **OR**:

```js
const filters = {
  dept: '',
  loc: ''
}

const deptFilter = document.getElementById('filterTextDept')
const locFilter = document.getElementById('filterTextLoc')

deptFilter.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  setFilters('dept', e.target.value)
})

locFilter.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  setFilters('loc', e.target.value)
})

const setFilters = (type, val) => {
  filters[type] = val === 'all' ? '' : val
  const r = Object.values(filters).filter(e => e).join('|')
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${r})`)
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.content').filter(function() {
    return regex.test($(this).text());
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filterTextDept">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
  <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
  <option value="Data Science">Data Science</option>
  <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
  <option value="Growth">Growth</option>
  <option value="Product Management">Product Management</option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
<select id="filterTextLoc">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Location</option>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
  <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
  <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
  <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
<table id="jobTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-list-search">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Account Manager</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Account%20Manager">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Associate Account Manager</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Associate%20Account%20Manager">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Diego</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Francisco or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Engineering</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Engineering">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Product Management, Fraud Risk</td>
      <td>Product Management</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Product%20Management,%20Fraud%20Risk">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Strategic Alliances</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Diego</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Strategic%20Alliances">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Head of Solution Consulting</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>San Diego, New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Head%20of%20Solution%20Consulting">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>IT Risk and Compliance Officer</td>
      <td>Compliance</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="IT%20Risk%20and%20Compliance%20Officer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Lead Data Scientist</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Lead%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Data Engineer</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Data%20Engineer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Data Scientist</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Product Manager, Document Verification</td>
      <td>Product Management</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Product%20Manager,%20Document%20Verification">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>Chennai</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Software%20Engineer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Software Engineer (All Levels)</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Software%20Engineer%20(All%20Levels)">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Solution Consultant</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>San Francisco or New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Solution%20Consultant">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Staff Software Engineer - Chennai</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>Chennai</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Chennai">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Staff Software Engineer - Core Platform</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Core%20Platform">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Logical **AND**:

```js
const filters = {
  dept: '',
  loc: ''
}

const deptFilter = document.getElementById('filterTextDept')
const locFilter = document.getElementById('filterTextLoc')

deptFilter.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  setFilters('dept', e.target.value)
})

locFilter.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  setFilters('loc', e.target.value)
})

const setFilters = (type, val) => {
  filters[type] = val === 'all' ? '' : val

  const regex1 = new RegExp(filters.dept)
  const regex2 = new RegExp(filters.loc)
  $('.content').hide();
  const list = $('.content').filter(function() {
    return regex1.test($(this).text()) && regex2.test($(this).text());
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filterTextDept">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
  <option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
  <option value="Data Science">Data Science</option>
  <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
  <option value="Growth">Growth</option>
  <option value="Product Management">Product Management</option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
<select id="filterTextLoc">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Filter by Location</option>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
  <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
  <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
  <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
<table id="jobTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-list-search">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Account Manager</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Account%20Manager">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Associate Account Manager</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Associate%20Account%20Manager">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Diego</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director, Account Executive</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Francisco or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director,%20Account%20Executive">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Engineering</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Engineering">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Product Management, Fraud Risk</td>
      <td>Product Management</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Product%20Management,%20Fraud%20Risk">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Director of Strategic Alliances</td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>San Diego</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Director%20of%20Strategic%20Alliances">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Head of Solution Consulting</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>San Diego, New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Head%20of%20Solution%20Consulting">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>IT Risk and Compliance Officer</td>
      <td>Compliance</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="IT%20Risk%20and%20Compliance%20Officer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Lead Data Scientist</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Lead%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Data Engineer</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Data%20Engineer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Data Scientist</td>
      <td>Data Science</td>
      <td>New York or Remote</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Data%20Scientist">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Product Manager, Document Verification</td>
      <td>Product Management</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Product%20Manager,%20Document%20Verification">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Senior Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>Chennai</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Senior%20Software%20Engineer">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Software Engineer (All Levels)</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Software%20Engineer%20(All%20Levels)">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Solution Consultant</td>
      <td>Growth</td>
      <td>San Francisco or New York</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Solution%20Consultant">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Staff Software Engineer - Chennai</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>Chennai</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Chennai">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>Staff Software Engineer - Core Platform</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>New York or Remote (East Coast)</td>
      <td>
        <a href="Staff%20Software%20Engineer%20-%20Core%20Platform">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### SUGGESTION

The concept you are applying here is based on that the **DOM** stores data, and you make your code work based on that data. A better approach would be to decouple the **DOM** and the data in your functions:

```
<tr class="content">
  <td>Account Manager</td>
  <td>Growth</td>
  <td>New York</td>
  <td>
    <a href="Account%20Manager">Link</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The **DOM** element above could be represented by a JavaScript object like this:

```
const content = [
  {
    jobTitle: "Account Manager",
    department: "Growth",
    location: "New York",
    link: "Account%20Manager",
    show: true
  }
]
```

You would have to add one render function to add the list of elements to the **DOM**:

```
const table = document.getElementById('jobTable')

let rows = content.filter(e => e.show).map({ jobTitle, department, location, link } => {
  let h = `
  <tr class="content">
    <td>${jobTitle}</td>
    <td>${department}</td>
    <td>${location}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="${link}">Link</a>
    </td>
   </tr>`
}).join('')

table.innerHTML = rows
```

This way you would just have to toggle the items `show` element (boolean - true, false) and run the render function - and it would always give you the list of items you want.